# MVC 5 - How to pull emdx data from controller to view

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, model-view

New to MVC! I can  pull data from my Database first Entity Framework model (emdx) just fine... Works Great - Coolest thing ever! But I have 2 questions:

1) I cannot get the data back to my view. (I want to display the security question (being returned from my stored proc in my DB First Entity Data Model - emdx) and allow the user to answer the question.
2) I also can't seem to redirect to a view in a different view folder (from the "View\Account" folder to the "View\Home" folder.

I'm pretty sure this is easy and I'm just missing something basic.

Here is my MVC controller code:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        string strEncr = "";
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                //Create Hash with Salt for For New PWs
                strEncr = Helper.ComputeHash(model.Password, "SHA512", null);
                string DBPW = "";

                string encryptedPassword = "";
                try
                {
                    using (var context = new WMSEntities1())
                    {
                         encryptedPassword = context.users
                            .Where(u => u.emailAddress == model.Username)
                            .Select(u => u.password)
                            .SingleOrDefault();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                //Test for match of PW between User and what's stored in DB
                bool flag = Helper.VerifyHash(model.Password, "SHA512", encryptedPassword);

                var loginInfo = databaseManager.LoginAndGetSecQuestion(model.Username, encryptedPassword).ToList();

                // Verification.
                if (loginInfo != null && loginInfo.Count() > 0)
                {
                    // Initialization.
                    var logindetails = loginInfo.First();

                    // Login In.
                    this.SignInUser(logindetails.emailAddress, false);
                    ViewBag.SecurityQuestion = logindetails.securityQuestion;
                    // Info.
                    return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", loginInfo);
                   // return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Setting.
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid username or password.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Info
            Console.Write(ex);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return this.View(model);
    }
```

Here is my code snipets in my view:

```
@*@model System.Data.DataSet*@
@model AodNetIntegration.LoginAndGetSecQuestion_Result
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Doc Center Login Screen";
}
@*<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>http://asmak9.blogspot.com/2016/03/aspnet-mvc5-integrating-existing.html
    <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>*@

@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginStage2", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <table cellspacing="5" style="width: 293px;">
 <tr>
     <td></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
     <td>
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.securityQuestion, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label, width= 50"  })
         @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.securityQuestion, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label, width= 50" })

         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.securityQuestion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })<br />
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.securityQuestionAnswer, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
         @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.securityQuestionAnswer, new { @class = "form-control" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.securityQuestionAnswer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" style="text-align: right;">

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
           </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
```

Here is the error I get:
 When it goes back to the Index page:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AodNetIntegration.LoginAndGetSecQuestion_Result]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'AodNetIntegration.LoginAndGetSecQuestion_Result'.
```

Controller Model Method:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace AodNetIntegration
{
   using System;

   public partial class LoginAndGetSecQuestion_Result
   {
      public int userID { get; set; }
      public string firstName { get; set; }
      public string lastName { get; set; }
      public string securityQuestion { get; set; }
      public string emailAddress { get; set; }
      public string securityQuestionAnswer { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have a view named `SecurityQuestions`? You need to add more code to understand what it is you trying to do (including the signature of that controller method and the name of that view). And nowhere in you code are you redirecting

Comment: Thanks - I made a few edits... I just figured out how to redirect to the correct view in a different folder (I had tried this before, but had a typo) Now I get the error in the post... I will post more code now

Comment: @StephenMuecke - is that enough? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Your returning `loginInfo` (which is your collection) when you should be returning `logindetails` (return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", logindetails);` But `loginInfo` can ever be `null` so here is no reason to test it, and you code should be `LoginAndGetSecQuestion_Result logindetails  = databaseManager.LoginAndGetSecQuestion(model.Username, encryptedPassword).FirstOrDefault(); if (logindetails == null) { // error } else { // return view };`

Comment: But its unclear why your using `return View(..)` instead of redirecting to a method that displays the view you have shown.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That was an attempt to get it working to another view. I updated the code and it worked going to the Home/Index View... Works perfectly now!! Thanks for helping me wrap my head around that concept. So clear in hindsight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query (var `loginInfo = databaseManager....`) is returning a collection of `LoginAndGetSecQuestion_Result`, not a single object, and you then return that collection to the view using

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", loginInfo);
```

but you view expects a single `LoginAndGetSecQuestion_Result` object, not a collection.

You code should be

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", logindetails);
```

However you can simplify your code by modifying the query to return a single object and testing for `null`

```
var loginInfo = databaseManager.LoginAndGetSecQuestion(model.Username, encryptedPassword).FirstOrDefault();
if (loginInfo != null)
{
    this.SignInUser(loginInfo.emailAddress, false);
    ViewBag.SecurityQuestion = logindetails.securityQuestion;
    return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", loginInfo);
}
else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid username or password.");
}
```